# C - Generate .h file from .c file

Tags: regular-expression, macro

Is there a good macro or regex expression that I can use in Vim to generate a `.h` file from a `.c` file?

For example, take the following `.c` file

```
// temp.c
// comment 1
// comment 2
void function1(int a, int b) {
    int x = 0;
    if (x == 0) {
        x = 1;
    }
    else { x = 2; }
}
```

and generate the following `.h` file

```
// temp.h
// comment 1
// comment 2
void function1(int a, int b);
```

My current method involves copying the `.c` file, renaming it as a `.h` file, then just deleting lines until it makes a header file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always in that format, you could do the following regex:

```
:%s/\v^\S.*\zs \{$\n(.*\n)*\}$/;
```

But this isn't a foolproof method because it relies on proper formatting. It's also pretty verbose and rather hard to understand. I would prefer a *global* command:

```
:g/^\S.*{$/norm $hc%;
```

This basically just says *on any line where `^\S.*{$` matches* (e.g. the start of a function) *run the following command*. The command to run is `$hc%;`, which in normal mode, will go to the end of the line, back one character, and change everything until the matching `}` with a `;`.

Comment: Might want to add `:keeppatterns` so that the search register, `"/`, if this is going to be automated

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @DJMcMayhem for his answer. For anyone else who comes to this post, I changed the regex a little bit and stuck it in a function like the one below.

```
" convert a .c file to a .h file
fun! s:convertC2H()
    w %:r.h
    tabe %:r.h
    execute 'g/^\S.*{$/norm $h%s;'
endfun
command! ConvertC2H :call s:convertC2H()
```

I edited the function to now also include copying the `.c` file out to a `.h` file (with the same name except the file extension).

Comment: Why not add the bit that creates the .h file into your function, too: make it fully automated!

Comment: Nice! I have more suggestions, though: You could replace the first line of your function with `%y`, which is a bit more concise, and doesn't require a mark. However, I'd probably replace the first *three* lines with the following two: 1. `w %:r.h` 2. `tabe %:r.h`. This also means your function doesn't affect any registers, and is possibly a bit simpler than using normal mode commands.

Comment: Yeah it worked great! Could you tell me what the first command you suggested does?

Comment: Sure! It calls the ex command `:yank` with a range of `%`, i.e. It yanks the entire file. See `help :yank` and `:help ranges`.

Comment: Oh oops. By "first" I meant this one `w %:r.h`. Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: That line creates the header file. See `:help :w`. Although it occurs to me now that that's not the right place for it! It would be better to `:write` the file *after* the `:global` command. (Or even just manually after the `:ConvertC2H` command completes).